# How to get click position on QPixmap

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

There is a **QLabel**:

```
self.image_label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
self.image_label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
```

to which I put **QPixmap** (generated dynamically):

```
pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(os.getcwd() + '\\deafult_title.png')
self.image_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
```

How to get xy coordinates of click, but in respect to image top-left corner? 
I know how to get position on label:

```
self.image_label.mousePressEvent = self.map_clicked
```

But label has some margin that changes when I move window.

I have also tried aligning **QPixmap** in label:

```
self.image_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
```

And now there is constant offset in x,y position, but I not sure if this is the best way to do this.

Is there some easy way to get click position in image coordination system?

Comment: QPixmap doesn't have mouse events. You will need to convert to label coordinates and align as you have mentioned. Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732551/qlabel-opencv-image-coordinates-in-qt

Comment: `xoffset = label.width() - pixmap.width() / 2`

Comment: Check this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4350068/1559401). Since - as @ZackGraber mentioned - a `QPixmap` doesn't have mouse events you have to deal with the `QLabel` that contains the `QPIxmap`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while but i found a solution by calculation the mouse click coordinates relative to the `QPixmap object`.

```py
label = QLabel(...)
img_pix = QPixmap(...)
label.setPixmap(img_pix)

# now you can get mouse click coordinates on the label by overriding `label.mousePressEvent`

# assuming we have the mouse click coordinates
coord_x = ...
coord_y = ...

# calculating the mouse click coordinates relative to the QPixmap (img_pix)
img_pix_width = img_pix.width()
img_pix_heigth = img_pix.height()

label_width = label.width()
label_height = label.height()

scale_factor_width = label_width / img_pix_width
scale_factor_height = label_height / img_pix_heigth

relative_width_in_img_pix = coord_x / scale_factor_width 
relative_height_in_img_pix = coord_y / scale_factor_height

relative_coordinates_in_img_pix = QPoint(relative_width_in_img_pix, relative_height_in_img_pix)
```